# Firebase remoteConfig not returning anything in react.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm currently working on an app that uses react.js, and we want to be able to have some custom config with firebase remoteConfig, but, since i don't have that much experience using it, i haven't been able to figure out how to fetch the data.

First of all, i want to show you my the way i'm doing it.

**This is my firebase config** (psdt: i'm using multiple firebase projects, so, that's why i had to put "third" when initializeApp)

```
import { getFirestore } from '@firebase/firestore';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_DISTRIBUCION_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_DISTRIBUCION_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_DISTRIBUCION_APP_ID,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DISTRIBUCION_DATABAS_EURL,
    measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_DISTRIBUCION_MEASUREMENT_ID,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_DISTRIBUCION_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_DISTRIBUCION_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_DISTRIBUCION_STORAGE_BUCKET,
};

export const distribucion = initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'third');

export const distribucion_db = getFirestore(distribucion);
```

**This is how i'm calling getRemoteConfig**

```
import { getRemoteConfig } from '@firebase/remote-config';

import { distribucion } from '../adapter/distribucionConfig';

export const remoteConfig = getRemoteConfig(distribucion);
```

**And this is how i'm fetching the values ussing useEffect**

```
const webConfig = async () => {
        const isConfighFetched = await fetchAndActivate(remoteConfig);
        if (isConfighFetched) {
            console.log(getValue(remoteConfig, 'map_config'));
        } else {
            console.log('fuck it');
            console.log(getValue(remoteConfig, 'map_config'));
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        webConfig();
    }, []);
```

This is what this is currently returning in my console

[image]

So, before you ask, yes, i do have values saved in my firebase app, i actually have two, one named 'authentication', and the other one 'map_config', they both are JSON values, but i'm not receiving that as you can see, what is going on ?